# Conditional JSON decoding based on a field value

Tags: json, elm

I have a need to decode JSON into an elm type like below:

Type

```
type User = Anonymous | LoggedIn String

type alias Model =
  { email_id : User
  , id : Id
  , status : Int
  , message : String
  , accessToken : AccessToken
  }
```

**JSON Message 1**

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "message": "Error message explaining what happened in server"
}
```

into type value

```
Model {
   "email_id": Anonymous
   , id: 0
   , status: 0
   , message: json.message
   , accessToken: ""
}
```

**JSON Message 2**

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "email_id": "asdfa@asdfa.com"
  "token": "asdfaz.adfasggwegwegwe.g4514514ferf"
  "id": 234
}
```

into type value

```
Model {
   "email_id": LoggedIn json.email_id
   , id: json.id
   , status: json.status
   , message: ""
   , accessToken: json.token
}
```

**Decoder information**

Above, "message" is not always present and email_id/id/token are always not present.

How to do this type of conditional decoding in elm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Json.Decode.andThen`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Json-Decode#andThen) lets you do conditional parsing based on the value of a field. In this case, it looks like you'll first want to pull out the value of the "status" field, `andThen` handle it separately based on whether it is a `1` or `0`.

Edit 2016-12-15: Updated to elm-0.18

```elm
import Html as H
import Json.Decode exposing (..)

type User = Anonymous | LoggedIn String

type alias Id = Int

type alias AccessToken = String

type alias Model =
  { email_id : User
  , id : Id
  , status : Int
  , message : String
  , accessToken : AccessToken
  }

modelDecoder : Decoder Model
modelDecoder =
  (field "status" int) |> andThen modelDecoderByStatus

modelDecoderByStatus : Int -> Decoder Model
modelDecoderByStatus status =
  case status of
    0 ->
      map5
        Model
        (succeed Anonymous)
        (succeed 0)
        (succeed status)
        (field "message" string)
        (succeed "")
    1 ->
      map5
        Model
        (map LoggedIn (field "email_id" string))
        (field "id" int)
        (succeed status)
        (succeed "")
        (field "token" string)
    _ ->
      fail <| "Unknown status: " ++ (toString status)

main = H.div []
  [ H.div [] [ decodeString modelDecoder msg1 |> Result.toMaybe |> Maybe.withDefault emptyModel |> toString |> H.text ]
  , H.div [] [ decodeString modelDecoder msg2 |> Result.toMaybe |> Maybe.withDefault emptyModel |> toString |> H.text ]
  ]

emptyModel = Model Anonymous 0 0 "" ""

msg1 = """
{
  "status": 0,
  "message": "Error message explaining what happened in server"
}
"""

msg2 = """
{
  "status": 1,
  "email_id": "asdfa@asdfa.com"
  "token": "asdfaz.adfasggwegwegwe.g4514514ferf"
  "id": 234
}
"""
```

Comment: Thanks again for the wonderful solution. It works. Could you pass me some links to understand how the JSON decoder's work as it seems a little unclear as to why Tasks and `andThen` are used here. Though it is very general purpose, I initially thought of Tasks as promises with task.then feature and hence the confusion.

Comment: Take another look at the link. It isn't using [`Task.andThen`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Task#andThen), it is using a function of the same name for Json decoders. Take a look at both sets of APIs and you'll see other similarities like `succeed` and `fail`. This lines up with basic Monad patterns, which are a common pattern in functional languages, although Elm purposely avoids calling them Monads because understanding Monads can be daunting. You don't need to understand Monads to parse Json.